# My program stops looping and i cannot figure out why

Tags: c, loops

if the user inputs the "value" as 1223445 the output should read as follows:

After change #1:  12235
After change #2:  135

the code is meant to take out two consecutive numbers with the same value.  the first loop works but then it stops and I cannot figure why. here is the code:

```
{

int count;  
int y;
int z;
int b;
int c;
int d;
int a;
int ct;
y = 0;
z = 1;
d = 0;
count = 0;
if (value > 0)
  while ((z * 10 + z) != (y % 100))
  {
    y = value % 10 + y * 10;
    z = y % 10;
    value /= 10;
    count = count + 1;
  }
  value = value * pow(10, count - 2);
  y = y / 100;
  count = count - 3;
  while(y > 0)
  {
    b = y % 10;
    c = pow(10, count);
    d = d + c * b;
    y = y / 10;
    count = count - 1;
  }
value = value + d;
ct = 1;
printf("After change #%d: %d\n", ct, value);
a = value;
while (a > 1)
  {
  if((a % 100) - (a % 10) - (10 * (a % 10)) == 0)
    Change(value);
  else
    a = a / 10;
  }
  return; 
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're treating the input value as an integer.  It may be easier to treat it as a string.  If you're not doing math on it, it's not a number.

Comment: it is a number, it is input by the user as 1223445, like I said at the top of the page

Comment: @bhaan: you've missed the point of the above comment - if you change `value` to a `string` then the code will be *much* easier to implement.

Comment: sorry, I should've mentioned that the code is for a class assignment and all numbers must be int's and we are not aloud to use arrays.

Comment: do you have braces after you first if statement to check that the value is not less than 0?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution: (not sure how you want to handle odd numbered repeats e.g. '111', '11111')

```
    public static long strip(long value, long sum) {
        if(value==0) return sum;

        long tens = value % 100;
        long ones = value % 10;
        if(ones*10 == tens-ones) {
            return strip(value /100, sum);
        }

        if(sum==0) sum +=(value%10);
        else {
            long x = (long)Math.ceil((Math.log10(sum)));
            sum =(long) (Math.pow(10,x) * ones + sum);
        }
        return strip(value /10, sum);
   }
```

Comment: That looks rather more like Java or C# than C (which is what the OP's question is tagged with)?